# Outlook Contact Sync

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, hook, email

I want to make an application which sync Outlook. I found there is an API service called Microsoft Graph, but it only allow me to retrieve the contact list.

Let's say I have 1000 users with 200 contacts. If I use polling method, then the complexity will be very complex. Do you guys have any idea to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get data from Microsoft Graph in sync with a 3rd party system (native app, backend service...) is to use [delta queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview). Personal contacts are [already supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) by the functionality.